# Is "somebody seeing the same problem?" a valid question type?

Tags: discussion, questions

I was scanning "new answers"; and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613335/wit-ai-bookmark-and-jump-disappeared/41484784#41484784).

That answer looked like the the typical "should be a comment, not answer" thing from the "I have that problem too" category to me.

So, I first downvoted and put up a delete request.

But then I had a closer look at other answers; and the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613335/wit-ai-bookmark-and-jump-disappeared) itself. And that question says:

*Does anyone have something similar experience? What happened?*

And of course, a statement like "yes, I have seen that" is answering parts of the question.

Now I am wondering: is all of that legit; or was already the question a really bad one which should have been downvoted/closed/deleted?

Comment: Only the sentence *Does anyone have something similar experience?* makes it a yes/no question. This can just be edited out and then we end up with *What happened?*, and the question is fixed in this regard (there are also *other* problems with this question, but being "yes/no" question is not one of them).

Comment: That is why they say in StackExchange rules to quote enough information from the documents you are posting links to — because, once the documents are gone, your question or answer immediately loses its context and becomes useless for future readers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I downvoted both the question and the answer.

The question should be closed regardless of the "*does anyone have something similar*" part, it simply doesn't show minimal efforts and it's too broad.

Note that not all questions with "does anyone have something similar" are necessarily bad; some of them might describe the problem well and be informative to others, but just suffer from wording problems. In such cases, a more experienced user might edit it and "convert" it to a good question with just changing to something like "why I am getting" or something else.

Answer (score -7):

Hmm... generally speaking, while a "Does anyone else have this problem?" type of question is very close to opinion-based, I can see at least one situation where it might be useful.

When attempting to troubleshoot an infrequently-triggered error, and/or an error that seems to trigger often for some users, but rarely for others, it could be used for information-gathering, to help profile the error.

> Does anyone else have this problem?  If so, please describe what you were doing when it occurred.

---

That said, while determining if others have encountered the same problem can be useful, I don't believe that it would necessarily be a good fit for Stack Overflow; this would depend on the software in question, with the question being a better fit for a different SE site <sup>(possibly Super User?  I'm not sure)</sup> in most cases.

One case I can think of that might fit SO would be if compiler maintenance teams are attempting to troubleshoot a particularly hard-to-find error that occurs when handling certain segments of standards-compliant code, and notice that people ask about it frequently on Stack Overflow.  In this case, they could ask the question here both so people can provide cases where they've triggered the error, and so it can be used as a duplicate source for other questions asking about the error (since this would provide the same information as actually *answering* the question).

[Yes, that's honestly the least-contrived case I can think of for when polling the users to see who else has encountered the same issue would be useful for SO, and conveniently, also the most useful case I can think of.]

---

If it's just a normal question, and not specifically intended to poll the users, then I agree with [Maroun Maroun's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340950/5386374).

Comment: How can someone else having the same problem be a matter of opinion? The question statement is misguided and should be something along the lines of "How can I fix this?" The user is obviously not looking to find out if they are the only person who has the problem, they're looking for a solution to the problem.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm not talking about the specific question linked by the OP, but about questions that specifically _are_ asking if anyone else has the same issue.  And I didn't say that this type of question _is_ opinion-based, but that it's _close_ to opinion-based (on the grounds that while answering, people are likely to state what they believe to be responsible for the issue, which could very well be an opinion if they don't have any technical data to support their belief).  I may need to clarify this, though.

Comment: Basically, my answer's intent was that it could cover the case where the asker actually _does_ want to know if others have encountered the same issue (which would likely be for the sake of gathering enough information to profile it), while deferring to Maroun Maroun's answer for the much more common case where it's just a poorly-worded request for help with the issue.  Do you think I should edit it to more clearly say this?

Comment: `The user is obviously not looking to find out if they are the only person who has the problem, they're looking for a solution to the problem.` -- Then that's what they should be asking for.